# Identify and update values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table full of these types of values

```
AU$97-AU$130
```

I would like to replace the values with the everything before the dash
So the above would become

```
AU$97
```

I know how to do this using PHP/MySQL using a few separate steps but is there a one time query in MySQL to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET col_name=SUBSTRING_INDEX(col_name, '-',1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(col_name, '-',1) from tblNAME
```

EDIT:
To update the col

```
UPDATE tblNAME set col_name=SUBSTRING_INDEX(col_name, '-',1);
```

Comment: Cool thanks - is there something I could add to that to make it update the value to the new value?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want everything with a dash to be affected:

```
UPDATE my_table SET col = SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-',1)
```